# Cypress + 2 Super Domains + AntiforgeryToken = Cypress can't be redirect

Tags: cypress, antiforgerytoken, samesite

I am currently working on setting-up a Cypress solution to test a product based on Nuxt and .NET. The product uses an SSO-based login page with a different super domain from the product.

This creates a problem with cookies. Indeed, access to the product generates a redirection to the SSO authentication page. And, following the validation of the authentication form, Chrome driven by Cypress enters a call loop with errors in the attributes of the cookie, in particular the value of the SameSite attribute which is incorrect compared to the expectation SSO side.

Currently, several features are disabled in the browser, namely :

- SameSiteByDefaultCookies
- CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating
- CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating
- IsolateOrigins
- site-per-process

Excerpt of cypress/plugins/index.js

```js
  on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
    if (browser.family === 'chromium') {
      launchOptions.args.push(
        "--disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies,CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating,CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating,IsolateOrigins,site-per-process"
      );
    }
    console.log(launchOptions.args);
    return launchOptions
  });
```

Even by disabling all the protections on the SSO, no way to make Cypress work.

[Here is an Excel file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_ZkMWy-oB8VCEoxSvOJ1sfef69eUJsig/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=108168950239560526512&rtpof=true&sd=true) with all of the HTML requests listed via the Chrome console. The file describes the differences between the Chrome driven by Cypress and a "classic" Chrome.

NB: adding `"chromeWebSecurity": false,` in the configuration of Cypress does not change anything

Not fully knowing what the underlying concerns are, I cannot describe the problem well. All the solutions proposed to similar problems exposed on various forums (StackOverFlow included) were not enough to solve mine. Can you help me please ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Alexander.

Comment: If my question is not understandable, feel free to tell me please. I have to solved this problem as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution for this SSO authentication.

Here is the code:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('authentificationSSO', (typedeCompte, login) => {
  let loginCompte = 'login';
  let motDePasseCompte = 'password';
  
  let baseUrlSSO = Cypress.env('baseUrlSSO') ? Cypress.env('baseUrlSSO') : '';
  let baseUrl = Cypress.config('baseUrl') ? Cypress.config('baseUrl') : '';

  cy.request(
    'GET',
    baseUrlSSO +
      '/Account/Login?${someParameters}%26redirect_uri%3D' +
      baseUrl
  ).then((response) => {
    let requestVerificationToken = '0';
    let attributsCookieGroupe = [];
    let nomCookie = '';
    let tokenCookie = '';
    const documentHTML = document.createElement('html');
    documentHTML.innerHTML = response.body;
    attributsCookieGroupe = response.headers['set-cookie'][0].split(';');

    const loginForm = documentHTML.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
    const token = loginForm.querySelector('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]')?.getAttribute('value');

    requestVerificationToken = token ? token : '';
    nomCookie = attributsCookieGroupe[0].split('=')[0];
    tokenCookie = attributsCookieGroupe[0].split('=')[1];

    cy.setCookie(nomCookie, tokenCookie, { sameSite: 'strict' });

    cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url:
        baseUrlSSO +
        '/Account/Login?{someParameters}%26redirect_uri%3D' +
        baseUrl,
      followRedirect: false,
      form: true,
      body: {
        Login: loginCompte,
        Password: motDePasseCompte,
        __RequestVerificationToken: requestVerificationToken,
        RememberLogin: false
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may have been caused by the chrome 94 update, which came out in October 21. Update 94 removed the `SameSiteByDefaultCookies` flag, so that fix no longer works.

If you're having the same issue I was, I resolved it by intercepting all requests, checking if they had a set-cookie header(s) and rewriting the SameSite attribute. There's probably a neater way to do it, as this does clutter up the cypress dashboard a little. You can add this as a command for easy reuse:

In your commands file:

```ts
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject> {
    disableSameSiteCookieRestrictions(): void;
  }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('disableSameSiteCookieRestrictions', () => {
  cy.intercept('*', (req) => {
    req.on('response', (res) => {
      if (!res.headers['set-cookie']) {
        return;
      }

      const disableSameSite = (headerContent: string): string => {
        return headerContent.replace(/samesite=(lax|strict)/ig, 'samesite=none');
      }

      if (Array.isArray(res.headers['set-cookie'])) {
        res.headers['set-cookie'] = res.headers['set-cookie'].map(disableSameSite);
      } else {
        res.headers['set-cookie'] = disableSameSite(res.headers['set-cookie']);
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Usage:

```ts
  it('should login using third party idp', () => {
    cy.disableSameSiteCookieRestrictions();
    //add test body here
  });
```

or alteratively, run it before each test:

```ts
  beforeEach(() => cy.disableSameSiteCookieRestrictions());
```

Comment: Hi willj,
Thanks for your reply and sorry for the delay. As I was not working on the project for a while, I could not test your solution.

The way it works has changed a bit: As soon as we access the basic product, we are redirected directly to an SSO portal for authentication and this one redirects us to the product after validated authentication.
Cypress is able to access the SSO portal and interact with it. However, the redirection does not work and implementing the code you provided to modify the "samesite" attribute has no effect.

Comment: At the moment I am trying to insert a second baseUrl dedicated to SSO in the Cypress config files and visit the SSO directly without going through the product. So far, I'm getting a "400 bad request" on the redirect. I'm still working on it.